# How get only the relevant data registered on the Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want to check "userId" and get only the relevant data registered on the Firestore,
but everything registered on the Firestore is printed out.
I don't know which part to fix.
I tried to change it according to the advice, but it hasn't changed.
I'm sorry, but I need your help.

app component typescript code is,

```
constructor(...) {
  this.userId = authService.currentUserId; // for load uid data 
  this.userCollection = afs.collection<User>('users/'+this.userId);
  this.user$ = this.userCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          id == this.userId;
          return { id, ...data };
      });
      })
  );
} 

<ion-item *ngFor="let data of user$ | async">
<ion-label>
{{data.myName}}
<p>{{data.userId}}</p>
</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Stop putting dense code into comments. You can update the original post

Comment: I don't know about Firestore, but I think you need use a FirestoneDataConverter and use withConverter as the docs says:https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    this.user$ = afs.doc<User>('users/' + this.userId).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but that way, the error was identified as below.
`Type 'Observable<{ userId: string; lastAppStartTime: Timestamp; myStoreCode: string; myStoreName: string; id: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.

  Type '{ userId: string; lastAppStartTime: Timestamp; myStoreCode: string; myStoreName: string; id: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

.ts(2322)`

Comment: I guess `this.user$` is defined as `Observable<any[]>`. You have to modify it to `Observable<any>`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,  but that way, the error was identified as below. 'Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DocumentSnapshot<User>'.
  Property 'doc' does not exist on type 'DocumentSnapshotDoesNotExist'.ts(2339)' I'm sorry your help didn't solve it, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess your code is different from my answer.